# Google Apps Script Hoisting and ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, hoisting

I've been trying to find an answer to this for a few weeks, but couldn't quite do this, so I decided to ask.

I sometimes get this error:

> ReferenceError: <SomeObject> is not defined

...whereas I know for sure that it is. The problem is that the object is located in a different file, so if I call the object from that file (or maybe even a third file), the code does work.

I believe this must have to do with how [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) works, meaning I'm trying to call an object before it's declared.

But then how does it work exactly when you have different files?

Here's an example:

If I have the following code in one file and I run `getID()`, it works:

```js
const SomeAPI = (function () {
  const _auth = new WeakMap();
  const _url = new WeakMap();

  class SomeAPI {
    constructor(url, user = DEFAULT_USER, pwd = DEFAULT_PWD) {
      _url.set(this, url);
      _auth.set(this, Utilities.base64Encode(`${user}:${pwd}`));
    }

    async fetch() {
      const headers = {
        Authorization: `Basic ${_auth.get(this)}`,
      };

      const options = {
        headers,
      };

      const response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(_url.get(this), options);
      const data = JSON.parse(response);
      return data;
    }
  }

  return SomeAPI;
})();

const LIST_DATA = (async () => await getListData())();

async function getListData() {
  const response = await new SomeAPI(ALL_SETTINGS['List API URL']).fetch();
  return Array.isArray(response) ? response[0] : response;
}


const getID = async () => {
  const listData = await LIST_DATA;
  const listId = listData.list_id;
  const id = {
    sheetId: SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId(),
    listId
  };
  console.log(id);
  return id;
};
```

However, if I move `LIST_DATA`, `getListData()` and `getID()` to a different file, I get:

> ReferenceError: SomeAPI is not defined

Overall the project is composed of 17 different files.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to position the file that someAPI is in above the file where the call is made

Comment: @Cooper you mean alphabetically?

Comment: In the new editor you can move the files.

Comment: Amazing, you'r a live saver, thank you! Feel free to write up your answer and I will gladly accept it!

Comment: BTW @Cooper it turns out that when you reload the project the file order is not persisted, so I did end up renaming `Code.gs` to `zCode.gs`, but you set me on the right track, so thanks for that

Comment: How do you reload the project?

Comment: F5 for example :)

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment by @Cooper to your question, moving the file up works.  I had the same problem with a class I created.  I moved the file with the class to the top and it solved my problem.